# Cannot find filepath that clearly exists.... Disabled macros, and verified directory

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have checked similar issues, but the solutions I have seen don't really address this problem. I am trying to temporarily [change the file access](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa223811(v=office.11).aspx) of a linked Excel sheet for a supervisor on a network drive. After doing some testing, I was able to validate that 2 directories I was testing are recognized. However, when trying to set a workbook object to a particular .xlsx file in those folders, I kept getting an error indicating Excel couldn't find the file (note the exact Excel name was copied and pasted in). Here is a sample of the code:

```
 Dim wb As Excel.Application
Dim s As String
If Me.Check9.Value = False Then
    s = CurrentPath & "\OurFile.xlsx"
Else
    s = "\\--UserProfile---Data\My%20Documents\Access%20Database%20Work"
End If
If Dir(s, vbDirectory) = "" Then
    MsgBox ("Good")
    Excel.Application.EnableEvents = False
    s = s & "\DummyQueryTested.xlsx"
    '*** Here is where the error is; we disabled macros above ***'
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(s)
    wb.ChangeFileAccess Mode:=xlReadWrite
Else
    MsgBox ("Bad")
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(s)
End If
Excel.Application.EnableEvents = True
```

A few last notes:

- There are On_Open macros, so that is why I tried using the EnableEvents=False command. The thought was those were preventing the files from opening
- I can't just move the file to another location because this is a file that is opened by an Access database as a link, and the company needs these files to be in the locations they are currently residing in.
- Finally, you can see I tested the network as well as local file paths and that is what the "Check9.Value" test was for...to test 2 different filepaths.

Any help would be appreciated. I have seen similar issues, but not exactly like this one. Is there any way to test further if there is some permission, or some setting these files have that might be causing problems?

Comment: Looks like you are concatenating `s` to its previous value, which is already a full filename. I dont think that's what your intention was.

Comment: Are you referring to this line?
s = s & "\DummyQueryTested.xlsx"
I just ran a MsgBox(s) after that line and it was the directory and path I wanted....are you suggesting that I just open without that filepath? I would think I need to specify a location.

Comment: Try replacing the %20 with just a regular space. You should only need to convert spaces to %20 when it's part of a URL.

Comment: if `Me.Check9.Value` is False then you set `s = CurrentPath & "\OurFile.xlsx"`. But then you set `s = s & "\DummyQueryTested.xlsx"`, i.e. you append another file name. Which should fail

Comment: I tried removing the %20 with a space but that just caused the Dir() to fail, so those were necessary. I am still unclear why the concatenation which just provides the full path to the actual file would fail. I looked at the Workbook.Open() function to be sure, and it seems you need the full path.

Comment: Sorry, I should have made clear that I have been testing with Me.Check9.Value being True.....hope that helps....still same error

Comment: Do you get the same error if you point it at some dummy .xlsx you create on your desktop or somewhere else?

Comment: When I moved a file to the desktop, the Dir() function showed that wasn't valid......or it returned a blank.

Comment: Does it work if you define wb as excel.workbook rather than excel.application?

It works for me with a desktop file, but strangely I have to set the file Read-Only first before I can set as ReadWrite. But, MSDN shows ChangeFileAccess operates on a workbook object.

Comment: Unfortunately, that still resulted in the same error message. Good thought though!

Comment: Are you running macro from Excel application or what?

Comment: Running it from Access....but the Access file refers to a linked Excel file which sometimes gets tied up if others are using it. We are trying to temporarily change permissions just so reporting can go through.